# .NET Standard on Linux

Tags: msbuild, mono, .net-core

I am doing some experiments in an uncommon stack. I have a .NET solution which is a mixture of *.NET Standard*, *Core* and regular .NET Framework projects. Both VS, framework and tooling are updated to latest available.

I'd like to use *gitlab CI* with a *docker runner over ubuntu*.

Before I introduced Core/Net Standard libraries (xprojs), I was able to build my solution by executing

```
MONO_IOMAP=case xbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" ./src/CoreLibrary/CoreLibrary.sln
```

, but since that, I keep getting the

> could not import "$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props"

error for all of my xprojs. Although I am able to build the xprojs with `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build`, the rest only can be built with xbuild. Right now I have two solutions to be able to build the non-xbuilds on linux separately to avoid the error. Is this the best I can do? Can somebody give me a hint on how to do this properly?

**Update**

To simplify things, let's say I have two projects within a solution: a *.NET Core Library* project targeting **netstandard1.4** (xproj) and the same old *.NET Console Application* targeting **.NET Framework 4.6.1** (csproj). The console application has a dependency to the netstandard library.

From Visual Studio, I am able to build the solution without any problem, both the projects get built properly. From my windows machine, I can use the `dotnet utility tool` as well to build/run xprojs. All works fine.

In my ubuntu based container though, mono is not capable to build the solution, it shows the error above (sounds reasonable, no VS installed there). I am only able to first build the xproj by using the properly working `dotnet utility tool` and have a separate solution file which does not contain the xprojs, only the console application and build it with xbuild.

My main concern (over the fact that this isn't a convenient solution) is that if a bug in VS gets fixed which makes it impossible at the moment to add references to xprojs from csprojs as *project reference*, I will not be able to use it since my csproj projects will need to be separated.

Comment: What is "the rest" that requires xbuild? .NET Core is in most cases self containing and is Mono free.

Comment: @LexLi I am simply experimenting for cases when I'd like to have CI for a solution which consists of many different project types. I've updated the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Microsoft clearly limits the scope to .NET Core on Linux. If you expand the scope to Mono, then the whole question becomes irrelevant to .NET Core or .NET Framework. Everybody knows Mono is not the replacement of .NET Framework, and any issue like yours is expected and not easy to fix (as not clear who should fix it and who is willing to fix it). I recommend you set a smaller experiment scope and save your own time and energy.

Comment: @LexLi You are probably right, thanks. Though my concern is that Microsoft is planning to take a step back and extend the scope of MSBuild over dotnet build and project.json. I am afraid that I will be in a position that I'll need to maintain multiple way of managing my project to work on both platforms.

Comment: Also see [How to install MSBuild on OS X and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32546121/608639), [Where to get msbuild for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47992371/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is a mixture of known issues and work in progress for .NET and .NET Core tooling. The `xproj` is a msbuild-wrapper for `project.json` based projects that makes it work with Visual Studio and other project types. The targets are installed into the global MSBuild location and only included in the .NET Core Tooling installer for Visual Studio.

Your options are:

1. The `preview2`/`preview2.1` versions of the dotnet cli know how to build libraries and console applications for the .NET "Full" Framework. It also knows about mono on linux and unix and also has an environment variable (`DOTNET_REFERENCE_ASSEMBLIES_PATH`) which allows you to tell it where your xbuild's reference assemblies are if it can't find it.

   This means you could make all your projects `project.json`-based, even the projects just targeting the full framework. The resolution of the `dependencies` section in `project.json` will find other `project.json`-based projects in the same folder or in the specified project locations in `global.json`.

   As long as all your projects are only libraries and console application, this allows you to build everything on linux and mac. However, you will need multiple `dotnet build` calls, one for each project, as the `dotnet` tool does not know about solution files. In Contrast, `dotnet restore` will find all projects in a folder  (or interpret `global.json > projects` afaik) and restore them all.
2. The latest released msbuild versions know about .NET Core and can build a `csproj` that targets .NET Core. But it is a mixture of `csproj` and `project.json` that is little known / used and will probably soon go away in its current form. There is only a short [guide on how to make it work with visual studio](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/aed38c1da30baa8b93598745d13ab98088f3a745/Documentation/project-docs/target-dotnetcore-with-msbuild.md). You could try to make it franken-build with that targets but it will probably not work out well.
3. The .NET Core tooling is moving to msbuild anyway. That means full support for `.sln`, `.csproj` and even custom msbuild projects as long as you have all the target/properties files.
   The MSBuild targets are distributed via a NuGet package (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) that will replace the globally installed msbuild targets for all c# project types. The dotnet sdk ships with a self-contained xplat build of msbuild and the project brings its target definitions via NuGet. As of now, these targets don't really work with mono but they [want to make it work with mono](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335) or at least build for full framework on linux.

   So if you wait a little for .NET Core tooling to mature, you will probably be able to `dotnet build your.sln`. Maybe also mono's xbuild will pick up the new msbuild changes.
4. 2-step build:

   Build all your libraries and .NET Core Apps with using `project.json`. Then package all libraries up as NuGet package using `dotnet pack` to a temporary location. The "classic" .NET projects can reference these packages via NuGet and restore using the temporary path as an additional source - either via a `NuGet.Config` file or a `-s ../tmp-packages` argument to `nuget`.

   This removes the possibility to code on both projects in VS and have newly added methods become available directly, but you can build all types of projects that `xbuild` supports (xamarin, web apps, ...).