# Where to get msbuild for Linux

Tags: linux, msbuild, .net-core

I want to build a .net core project on Windows and Linux.

For Windows I use MSBuild, simply downloaded the `Build Tools für Visual Studio 2017` from [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en/downloads/).

But where do I get MSBuild for Linux from? Based on the GitHub Project site, it should be available on some Linux distributions ([README.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/README.md)). I do not want to compile it myself (for some reasons).

I **do not** want to use xbuild, but pure MSBuild.

Comment: Follow the guides at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x , for .net core you invoke it with the command `dotnet msbuild`

Comment: Thanks. Make this an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: BTW, if you use Mono 5.x, there is no more `xbuild`, and the command becomes a wrapper over `msbuild`. So yes, `xbuild` is gone for ever.

Comment: Ah, good to know :)

Comment: Note that for now the msbuild bundled with Mono is different than the msbuild included with the dotnet sdk. The version bundled with mono supports targeting the .NET framework while the msbuild bundled with dotnet does not. See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/335

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install MSBuild on OS X and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32546121/608639)

Comment: @jww you are right, but I'd say the answers here are way better than the question you linked to ;) Furthermore the answer in the link is a bit outdated. Therefore I would keep this question here and its answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can obtain .NET Core SDK as described in these URLs.
It is divided for each linux distribution.

[RHEL](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxredhat)
[Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu)
[Debian](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxdebian)
[CentOS/Oracle](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxcentos)
[SLES/OpenSUSE](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxopensuse)

---

**Updated:2019-03-19**

[.NET Downloads for Linux, macOS, and Windows](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)
Select the tab for the desired OS and then download.

related.
[Microsoft/msbuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild)
[msbuild/documentation/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild.md](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Building-Testing-and-Debugging-on-.Net-Core-MSBuild.md)

> **Getting .Net Core MSBuild binaries without building the code**
>   The best way to get .NET Core MSBuild is by installing the [.NET Core SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk), which redistributes us. This will get you the latest released version of MSBuild for .NET Core. After installing it, you can use MSBuild through `dotnet build` or by manual invocation of the `MSBuild.dll` in the dotnet distribution.

Comment: All of these links are getting redirected to a generic tutorial.

Comment: @filmor, The site structure of Microsoft has changed since the time of writing the article.

Comment: _you can use MSBuild through `dotnet build`_ thank you

Comment: Update 2013-04-19: Click "All .NET 7.0 downloads" and pick your desired version