# How to install Visual C++ build tools (14.0+) in CentOS 8?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, centos8, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I want to install Visual C++ Build Tools in a machine that is running in CentOS 8.
I went through many answers, but everything is based on either Windows or Mac.

I also tried

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

But this one too doesn't help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get msbuild for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992371/where-to-get-msbuild-for-linux)

Comment: @Zachary Sure, it did answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching many websites, finally, I got the answer from the comment section of this question.
[Where-to-get-msbuild-fro-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992371/where-to-get-msbuild-for-linux)