# How do I install MSBUILD on macOS?

Tags: .net, macos, f#, msbuild

Sorry for the simple question, but I already didn't find the answer on google. And there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546121/how-to-install-msbuild-on-os-x-and-linux) here, which seem outdated.

In the [releases](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases) MS just provide the source.

So a link would be useful.

Answer (score 11):

`Msbuild` is contained in the `Mono` [release](http://www.mono-project.com/download/).

Then you might need to add the Mono bin directory to `path`.

```
# in zsh
path+=('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin')
```

Comment: The .net core SDK also contains an msbuild distribution - the `dotnet msbuild` command exposes. There are some differences though between mono's msbuild and the .net core ones